# Python script for checking if website has URL to other website

Tags: python

Let's say I have an xls or csv file (on some cloud) with list of website which contain URL to some content on my website. I'd like to write a script that goes to given website, checks if the link is still there and if it has 'follow' attribute. Which tool and library will be optimal for it. I think about using Selenium for this.

Comment: If no interactivity is needed, then perhaps **Beautiful Soup** would do.

Answer (score 0):

For manually selecting websites to check, try:

```py
import urllib
Url = urllib.request.urlopen(input(“Website to check?(Format: http(s)://www.(WebPageDomain).(WebPageUrlEnder)/(OPTIONAL:Sub-page)\n>> “)

if Url.read().contains(input(“Your website name?\n>> “)):
    # do thing
```

This may work, or it may not. I had no time to check. If you get issues with the method read() then look at some documentation

Answer (score 0):

> yes, you can use selenium to automate the stuffs in python. 
>   
> Alternatively, you can read the csv/xls files and store the values
>   as a dataframe using pandas in python.
>  You can iterate over the
>   websites and store the result that the website is working or not.

```
# sample code for storing csv/xls in dataframe
filepath = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath) || pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col=0)
print(df)

# sample code for checking website exists
import requests
url = 'http://www.example.com'
request = requests.get(url)
if request.status_code == 200:
    print('Web site exists')
else:
    print('Web site does not exist')
```

and finally store the result in the form of csv/xls.